# How to pass parameters to a symbol method call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model concern which adds a method 't' allowing the models fields to be translated va I18n:

```
module  Translatable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def t(field_name)
    I18n.t("models.#{self.class.table_name}.#{translation_tag}.#{field_name}")
  end
```

Model:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Translatable
```

This works fine almost everywhere using:

```
@model.t(:name)
```

However I have a select field which uses this code to map the entries:

```
Model.all.order(name: :asc), :id, :name
```

And I want :name to use the translatable method instead. The below works, but I'm getting a missing argument error (quite clear why):

```
Model.all.order(name: :asc), :id, :t
```

However this doesn't work:

```
Model.all.order(name: :asc), :id, :t(:name)
```

What is the correct way to pass variables to methods when they are called as symbols?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't in this context.

Either create a dedicated method in your model to handle the name layout or use `map` before the select.

```
def i18n_name
  t(:name)
end

select Model.all.order(name: :asc), :id, :i18n_name
```

or

```
Model.all.map { |p| [ p.t(:name), p.id ] }
```

More information [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select)

Note: I would not recommend placing i18n translations in your models, it should be in presenters. Have a look at [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper)